# How to add a wait in the feature file for the karate framework?

Tags: user-interface, web, automation, karate, wait

```
And click("//button\[text()=' Next '\]")
And match driver.title == 'ONE'
And click("//\*\[@id='BusinessUnits'\]/li\[2\]/a")
```

I want to add waiting time between 2nd and 3rd line. How can I add that ?

I have tried adding sleep that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay()` refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#delay

Note that you normally never need to use that if you write tests the right way.